# Throws exception when Bind DataContex.[0]?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

My `Datacontext` is a `ObsevableCollection`,

I need to bind it with a `Value <double>` property

The below binding not works in my case, (as it a property of dependency object within class of type `ObervableCollection<T>)`

```
 Value="{Binding [0]}"
```

So i need to bind something like this

```
Value="{Binding DataContext.[0], ElementName=grid}"
```

But it throws exception

> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding.Path'

How can i resolve this?

Thanks in advance
JoyRex

Answer (score 1):

Give it as,

```
Value="{Binding DataContext[0], ElementName=grid}"
```

Comment: I think in `ElementName="grid"` should not be the quotes around `grid`: `Value="{Binding DataContext[0], ElementName=grid}"`.